# How to dynamically remove legend in charts using Jasper reports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to dynamically remove the legend from a chart using the [Jasper](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports) report API?

I have a chart to display dynamically based on some configurations, which includes the legend as a option, so if legend is unchecked I need to hide or remove the legend form the chart.
Is there any function available in the API which can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChart.html) there is a method `setShowLegend(Boolean)`

You can obtain the chart this way (I haven't tested it, so there might be some issues):

```
InputStream is = this.getClaa().getResourceAsStream(jasperFilePath);
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);
JRChart chart = (JRChart) report.getDetail().getElementByKey("chart");
chart.setShowLegend(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: Thank you
but how do i instantiate JRChart's constructor?

this is my code to fill the jasper object:-
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlPath, jasperpath);
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperpath, param,
      connection);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, htmlFile);


how do i make an instance out of this

Comment: I edited my response with the details. I'm note sure if it would work, but give it a try.

Comment: i tried it, but i guess its deprecated:-

JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load (jrxmlPath);
     JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
JRChart chart = (JRChart) jasperReport.getSummary().getElementByKey("element-1");
chart.setShowLegend(Boolean.FALSE);

Comment: there is no exceptions, even if i try to print 'chart.getShowLegend()' it returns null, but if try to print width and height of the chart 'chart.getHeight()' it works.

Comment: What version of JasperReport are you using?
P.S. edit your question - it points to a wrong Jasper :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the JasperReport description syntax (the XML tags composing the jrxml file) do not let you do such a thing.

Here is a pie chart description with legend (default) :

```
<pieChart>
    <chart isShowLegend="true">
        <reportElement x="19" y="18" width="518" height="196"/>
        <chartTitle/>
        <chartSubtitle/>
        <chartLegend/>
    </chart>
    <pieDataset>
        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></keyExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
        <labelExpression><![CDATA["<"+$F{name}+">"]]></labelExpression>
    </pieDataset>
    <piePlot>
        <plot/>
        <itemLabel color="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </piePlot>
</pieChart>
```

and here the same chart without legend :

```
<pieChart>
    <chart isShowLegend="false">
        <reportElement x="19" y="18" width="518" height="196"/>
        <chartTitle/>
        <chartSubtitle/>
        <chartLegend/>
    </chart>
    <pieDataset>
        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></keyExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
        <labelExpression><![CDATA["<"+$F{name}+">"]]></labelExpression>
    </pieDataset>
    <piePlot>
        <plot/>
        <itemLabel color="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </piePlot>
</pieChart>
```

The only difference is the **isShowLegend** attribute in the **chart** tag. (You can access it in the chart properties panel in iReport).

But this attribute is a value, and you can't use a expression such as :

```
$P{DISPLAY_LEGEND}.booleanValue();
```

Where `DISPLAY_LEGEND` would be a parameter of the report (type is [java.lang.Boolean](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html))

---

If you really want to realise a such thing, following trick should work:

Define you graph to time. One with legend and one without. Graph should be overlapped.
*(you can do so by coping the concerned tag directly in the XML text)*

After that edit the **print when expression** property of each graph, in oder that just one of the 2 graph is printed, depending of a condition.

Here is the result example with my `DISPLAY_LEGEND` parameter. (but it could be an other condition, also calculated. Important is that the two conditions are symmetric)

```
<pieChart>
    <chart isShowLegend="true">
        <reportElement x="19" y="18" width="518" height="196">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{DISPLAY_LEGEND}]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <!-- end of the chart definition-->
    </chart>
    <!-- pieDataset and piePlot-->
</pieChart>
<pieChart>
    <chart isShowLegend="false">
        <reportElement x="19" y="18" width="518" height="196">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!$P{DISPLAY_LEGEND}.booleanValue())]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <!-- end of the chart definition-->
    </chart>
    <!-- pieDataset and piePlot-->
</pieChart>
```

---

I also wanted to mention that you can access the the JFreeChart Object during the report generation. Here some forum posts, that helped me doing so :

- [display value beside each point on a line graph](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=39730)
- [How to put "Label" in Line Graph?](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=44396)
- [Customizing a chart - for newbies!](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=17737)